# Functionality of scanf function in c

Tags: c

I would like to know how scanf function was working in this case.

```
main()
{
    printf("%d\n",scanf("%d"));
}
```

output :

./a.out

5

1

Here the scanf is waiting for input I entered 5.

I can see that scanf is successful and returned 1.

I really didn't understand where the integer 5 is stored.

Comment: This is invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, Thanks for reply, is it just undefined behaviour, I thought there may be any reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Please explain fully why you wrote that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's UB.  OP knew it was UB.  UB ensued.  OP posted the UB to SO for explanation of UB.

Comment: @MartinJames I was trying to code something, there I made mistake of this scanf(), but still the program was compiled properly, so I checked further what it is returning, so I wanted to know the reason of this behaviour

Comment: @Ash it is in the Appendix J.2 of the C11 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer 5 wasn't stored in any known location, although it may have been stored in some completely random location, because you didn't provide a location for it. It's fortunate that your program didn't crash. This is completely undefined behavior.

`scanf("%d")` should be followed by the address of an `int`. But you shouldn't put a call to `scanf()` in a parameter list in the first place.

Comment: `scanf()` is like any other function that returns a value.    If it is called in a valid way (which it isn't in this question) its return value can be passed to any other function - including `printf()`.

Comment: @Peter I agree completely, but I think it's bad practice to use it in this way, particularly because the order of evaluation of operands in a function call is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Logicrat Thanks for your answer.